# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array with json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to combine two array's together so I can add that to a json file what already exists.

I've tried to use array_push() but I keep getting the same error that the existing decoded json file is not an array but an object.

```
$new_user = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'IP' => getUserIpAddr()
];

$myJSON = json_encode($new_user);
$old_json =  file_get_contents("players.json");
$json_decode = json_decode($old_json);
array_push($json_decode, $new_user);
print_r($json_decode);
$json_file = fopen('players.json', 'w');
fwrite($json_file, json_encode($json_decode));
fclose($json_file);
```

If I print the `$json_decode` I get this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [name] => name 
    [email] => name@gmail.com 
    [IP] => ::1 
)
```

with the error message:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in

how do I turn the json content into a array?

Comment: `$json_decode = json_decode($old_json, true);` to get the Json as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't do `json_encode()`  before `array_push()`

Use `true` as second parameter to `json_decode()`

```
$new_user = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'IP' => getUserIpAddr()
];

//$myJSON = json_encode($new_user); not needed

$old_json =  file_get_contents("players.json");

$json_decode = json_decode($old_json,true); // true as second parameter

array_push($json_decode, $new_user); // push array not json_encoded value

print_r($json_decode);

$json_file = fopen('players.json', 'w');

fwrite($json_file, json_encode($json_decode));

fclose($json_file);
```

Comment: @FrisoStolk  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

If it is telling you that the first param to `array_push` is an object then force  your decoded JSON into an array by adding a second parameter to the `json_decode($str, true)`

```
$new_user = [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'IP' => getUserIpAddr()
];

//$myJSON = json_encode($new_user);

$old_json =  file_get_contents("players.json");

// CHANGED HERE
//$json_decode = json_decode($old_json);
$json_decode = json_decode($old_json, true);

array_push($json_decode, $new_user);
print_r($json_decode);
$json_file = fopen('players.json', 'w');
fwrite($json_file, json_encode($json_decode));
fclose($json_file);
```